# List view threshold prevents adding new records to list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view-threshold

I have a list with over 5000 items.  The list has indices so no errors are generated when viewing or editing items, however, users generate the following error when attempting to add new items.

“The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

As a test, I copied the list then deleted half the records.  Once the number or records drops below 5000 users are again able to add records.  I also tried alternating between the default NewForm.aspx and a custom form, however, the results are the same – users without Site Collection privileges are unable to add new records to the list.  The error logs show the following alert.

04/12/2015 15:58:43.28  w3wp.exe (0x173C)                           0x1B08  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Lists/xxx/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsharepoint%2Fdistribution%2Fcentral%20maintenance%2FContractor%20and%20Resource%20Planning%2FLists%2FDSBNCapability&ContentTypeId=0x0100D6F03FC921746645ABB7F8B85A1C3BBF&IsDlg=1) 617fc1ab-4716-4128-80ab-67887d6d1d90

I know I can disable throttling on the list but want to understand what is happening.  How can I modify the NewForm.aspx so that it does not query the entire list when calling the New Item form?  Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: Does the error occur when the newform is requested?  Or upon saving a new item?

Comment: Has someone already modified the form?

Comment: The error occurs when the form is requested and the error occurs with the default newform.aspx or a custom form.  Thanks.